# Bullets in jsp forms not encoded properly

Tags: jsp, unicode, character-encoding

I have a web app with a jsp form. if a user copies bulleted text from word into the form the bullets are turned into strange characters Ã¢Â¿ and submitted by the form. Is there a a way to prevent this at the form level inside jsp. I am using UTF-8 encoding

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Comment: Are you saying that bullets are turned into `Ã¢Â¿` at exactly the moment when the enduser pastes them into the form?

Comment: No they are not, but if the form updates then they are redisplayed that way

Comment: Your initial question implied otherwise, but that'll be the language barrier. I've posted concrete answer how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the request body character encoding to the same *before* the first request parameter is ever extracted from the request body, otherwise it will be the servletcontainer dependent default one, which is often ISO 8859-1.

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

A sane place to perform this job would be a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info).

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's not just bullets - every non-ASCII character will likely be mangled.

Your page is output in UTF-8 encoding, but you're not handling your input as UTF-8. Unfortunately the Servlet specification, amongst its many grievous mistakes, requires that input is handled using ISO-8859-1. Changing that behaviour completely is a pain and differs across different servlet containers. [Some Tomcat-focused background](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding).